# PreloadJS, how can i test if i really use the preloading system?

Tags: canvas, createjs, image-preloader

I'm working on a 2d isometric map with canvas and [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com). I had memory problems so i use PreloadJs and i have loaded all my tiles with the lib like :

```
preload = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
preload.loadFile({id: "first", src:"MY_URL"});

myImage = preload.getResult("first");
new createjs.Bitmap(myImage);
```

I have loaded lots of tiles like that.
So, how can i test if what I'm doing is useful or not ? I don't really show a difference between before and now.. Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

PreloadJS just helps to manage the loading and access of assets in your application. Regardless of how you load them, images are always going to take the same amount of memory once loaded.

You could look into deferred/demand loading (loading only the tiles you need, and unloading them when no longer needed). Also, consider combining your tiles into spritesheets - this likely won't reduce memory, but will reduce the number of http requests.